# Can fuseki be config to use two different type of dataset to created a unioned dataset?

Tags: jena, fuseki, tdb, knowledge-graph

I'm thinking that to create two dataset, one is in memory, which frequently changed, another is tdb, which is read-only, can be created as one dataset, but in the back, which in memory remain in memory, and which in tdb remain in tdb. If not, can two tdb dataset be union as one dataset?

Comment: You can put graphs from different datasets into a new dataset.

Comment: @AndyS sorry to trouble, But if I made one dataset in memory, another in tdb, whether union them in memory or in tdb?

Comment: The general dataset, with graphs from each of the other datasets (limitation - each named graph in the general dataset can only come from one other dataset) leaves the graph in its original storage and directs request to the right place.

Comment: @AndyS thanks, I have done a little research for this, for now I can make a default graph which union two different backend graph(one is tdb, one is in memory). But I still have a problem, when I query the default query, how can fuseki know when to use memory db and when to use tdb?

Comment: I have taken a peek about jena's code, I found in "MultiUnion" class, it delegate the query to subGraph which it contains. I don't know whether I am correct.

Comment: yes - "multiunion" itself has no state - it accesses the subgraphs and makes sure the triples are not returned more than once.